# Making a button read a string from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm a beginner developer for iOS. I'm using objective c to develop an app. I want a button to be able to read a string from an array. What I mean by this is NOT to set the string as what the button displays. I want it to be able to get the string so I can use AVSpeechSynthesizser to read the string aloud. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: It would help to provide some context or code samples related to the question you are asking.

Comment: Sorry guys. I know code examples etc are helpful but I'm not exactly sure where to start. If you could just give me an example of how you would do it I would be grateful. Just set the arrays as exampleArray and the same for buttons etc

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide any code or details about your problem.

I have to make assumption that you just want to read something from array while button is tapped.

Either using storyboard to create the button object and its handler or manually add the handler.

Let's say you have the button object named 'exampleButton', if you choose manually add the handler,

```
[exampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Let's say your array name is `exampleArray`, and you want to access the first element.

**EDIT:**
use `firstObject` instead `objectAtIndex:0` since the latter one will crash the app if the array is empty.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    // becareful, if the array is empty, firstObject will return nil.  
    // If you use [exampleArray objectAtIndex:0], it will crash
    id obj = [exampleArray firstObject]; 
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", obj); // now you have the string object.
    }
}
```

You have to learn more if you still cannot get yourself started with above code.

Comment: Thanks. Will that code set the buttons label to the string? If so I don't want that

Comment: No. setting the button's label is another line of code. You should really walk through any books or documents. It feels you are even not able to read code or understand the UI concepts.

Comment: If your 'exampleArray' is empty this will crash, you should probably use firstObject as it will return nil instead.